# Display TinyMCE inputted text causing undisplayable characters

Tags: php, javascript, tinymce, html-entities, html-escape-characters

[image: Text error]

Website is set to use UTF-8 so this should not be the issue:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Looking in the TinyMCE "View Source" option here is what the code looks like:

```
<p>Posted by J. King</p>
<p>This is just a test. &nbsp;This is just a test.</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

And looking in the database it is sanitised and converted to the following:

```
&lt;p&gt;Posted by J. King&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;This is just a test. &amp;nbsp;This is just a test.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;
```

I'm using [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) to convert the saved database text back to the proper formatting it should have. I thought I did everything by the book here, and didn't think I did anything wrong? Is there something I can do to fix this?

Comment: can you check for the tinymce editor iframe to have a charset set?

Comment: It is not within an iframe.... @Thariama